# spring xd with rabbit transporter not picking up

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-xd

I am trying to use rabbit as my transporter in spring-xd. Earlier, I installed redis and configured redis properties in servers.yml and it was working.

Now, I moved to rabbitmq, and installed rabbitmq and able to run the service rabbitmq-server.
I made the following changes in servers.yml

```
xd:
    transport: rabbit

#RabbitMQ properties
spring:
  rabbitmq:
   host: FQHN
   port: 5672
   username: guest
   password: guest
   virtual_host: /
```

But, when I am starting xd-admin and container, still container taking redis as a transporter.

Redis properties are commented in servers.yml.

Please help me on this.

Thanks,
-Suyodha

Answer (score 0):

I use rabbit transport all the time, with no problems.

First, I suggest you move to the [recent 1.0.0.RELEASE](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/30/spring-xd-1-0-ga-released). The rabbit host and port are now provided in the `addresses` property

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
   addresses: FQHN:5672
   ...
```

How are you launching the container and admin? Do you have any `XD_` environment variables set? Using the supplied scripts, the `servers.yml` settings will normally override the `application.yml`. It must be on the classpath. If you can't figure it out, post a DEBUG log of the container startup somewhere (too big for here) with DEBUG enabled for `org.springframework`.

Comment: Hi Gary, I have set all configuration settings, XD_HOME,XD_CONFIG,XD_MODULE_CONFIG and MODULE_NAME which are available in .bashrc.  Is it causing the issue.??  I do start xd-admin and xd-container in one machine and xd-container in other machine. servers.yml where I changed to rabbitmq and restarted all the things. when I start xd-container, it is still showing the transport:redis in its console. I completely removed redis entries in servers.yml and restarted. But, still it is showing redis as a transport. Customer suggestion is to use M7 only. Please help me on this. Thanks,Suyodha

Comment: It must be a classpath problem; as I said, post a DEBUG log somewhere if you can't figure it out.